# Reset localStorage data via server-side / Flask + JS

Tags: javascript, python, flask, local-storage

I am making a minigame about maps, where each day there will be 3 available maps corresponding to levels (currently renovating the maps manually via a flask route.

I am storing users stats (winning streaks and so on) locally in the browser because I don't want to bother me server side with creating accounts and leading with DB.

I would like that when I access my flask route (or later when I'll figure out how to execute the function automatically) to reset some specific values into the local storage but I struggle to figure out.

I have tried to send some sort of "flag" and pass it to my html via jinja but the data doesn't "stick" there. It seem to only work if someone access personally the route before.

```
@app.route("/generate_maps") 
def generate_and_save_maps():
# my function there
reset_signal = True
return render_template('homepage.html', reset_signal=reset_signal)
```

Then I just call it in my html (resetSignal.js is basically a check that removes localStorages if signal is existent) :

```
<script> var resetSignal = {{ reset_signal | lower }}; </script>
<script src="static/js/resetSignal.js"></script>
```

Comment: The server has no access to the browser's `localStorage`. It can only be access with client-side JavaScript. Can you use a cookie instead?

Comment: I don't know tbf. It's my first time creating an app and I havn't covered cookies yet.
 
I just read about it and it seems that the fact cookies can expire could be interesting. You were suggesting to set these temporary values as cookies so they would expire automatically after a determined amount of time (let's say I generate maps every 12h) ?

My only issue is that users can disable them but I could just alert them that the game mechanics would not work if so...

Comment: I'm suggesting using cookies because they can be set from the server.

Comment: Users can change local storage, too.

Comment: If you're worried about users overriding it, you shouldn't use anything on the client, it must be on the server.

Comment: I don't think I care that much. If users override it they will loose their own statistics.

If I use cookies, will the signal affect every user even if they do not access the route ?

Comment: Cookies are per-user, just like local storage. See [differences between cookies and local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)